# Tensorboard via Google Cloud Platform

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, tensorboard

I was following [this walkthrough](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/running_pets.md) on creating a pet detector using tensorflow object detection.

I tried to run the following:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
tensorboard --logdir=gs://mybucket
```

and then I got this error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnimplementedError: File system scheme gs not implemented
```

Anyone have any idea about how to access the google cloud platform logs through tensorboard? I can open tensorboard in the browser fine, but it doesn't show any data.

I'm sure it's fairly straightforwards, thanks!

(See section 'Monitoring Progress with Tensorboard
' in the walkthrough link)

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Tensorflow on a Compute Engine instance? If so, why are you trying to point your tensorboard to a cloud bucket? If you are running TF on a Google Cloud Compute Engine instance, it just creates a log file in the local file system and you point to it in the usual way. Then, open the browser at the IP address of that VM and it should work fine. Make sure to have enabled HTTP traffic when creating your VM

** UPDATE:

As discussed in the comment, you might want to look int using Google's `gcsfuse` utility if you want `tensorboard` to put its output onto a cloud storage bucket.

Read the [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/gcs-buckets) on installing `gcsfuse`. Once installed, create a directory on your VM, fuse that directory with your cloud bucket, and use that directory as output for `tensorboard`:

```
sudo mkdir vm_dir
sudo gcsfuse cloud_bucket vm_dir
tensorboard --logdir=vm_dir
```

As a disclaimer, I haven't tried this myself, but can't see why this shouldn't work. Also keep in mind that once you stop/start your VM, the fuse will be lost, so don't forget to issue the `gcsfuse` command again to link the directory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

I am running tensorflow and the training on the compute engine but setting it all up from my local machine a la the walkthrough. I don't have a compute engine VM enabled.

Comment: Well if you insist on doing it this way, then try installing the gcsfuse tool on your compute engine machine, which allows you to link a google cloud storage bucket with a folder on the machine. I will update the answer with some links and basic commands on how to do it...